# Strange URL requests via Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04, what is the malicious user trying to do?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, brute-force-attacks

A malicious user has been trying to browse to strange URLs that don't exist on my server. One such request turned out to be url encoding:

> %2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%30+%2D%6E

This urldecoded to:

> -d allow_url_include=on -d safe_mode=off -d suhosin.simulation=on -d disable_functions="" -d open_basedir=none -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -d cgi.force_redirect=0 -d cgi.redirect_status_env=0 -n

This next one seems to be requesting an image

> "J\x00\x00\x00&8B\x81\x90=Ve\xBE\x0C:\x8B7 m\xD8x\x8Eo\x83\xA9\x8D\xEB{'\xD8\x1A\xF0j\xB2\x95Mu}\x13\x5C\xB5\xAFe\xCD\xC6\xE7&N\xBA\x0B\xF1\xFB\xDCcD\x17\xCA]{H\x8AY\x90M\x04\xC5G\x83g\xF6\xB0U\xC2\xDEj\xE2\xE8n" 400 181 "-" "-"

What is this malicious user trying to do? This is a Ubuntu 14.04 server running nginx to serve up a django application.

Comment: `-d auto_prepend_file=php://input` if that worked the raw post body (would have been a post request) would run as php code.

Comment: I'd block that IP and call it a day...

Comment: I blocked it, the attacker goes through a different proxy each time though so it's an ongoing threat.

Comment: How might I disallow these types of requests? All of this is on top of constant brute-force ssh auth attempts

Comment: some [security hints here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-webserver-security.html).